# Python throws exception on bypassing True as method parameter

Tags: python, exception

I have the following concern - Why does the following code throw exception on param2?:

```
def paramcheck(param1, param2):
    try:
        if param1:
            print('param1: ' + param1)
        if param2:
            print('param2: ' + param2)
    except:
        print('error')

paramcheck(False, True)
```

I'm using python 3.4.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Using a catch-all `except` as you've done here is almost always a bad idea. In this case, it hid the error message that would have easily solved your problem for you.

Comment: I understand that, but this is a general question why False doesn't throw an exception while True does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hadn't quashed the error message you would have gotten a helpful message:

```
>>> param1 = True
>>> print('param1: ' + param1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects
```

As the error says, you can't concatenate strings with booleans in Python. You have to convert the boolean manually:

```
print('param1: ' + str(param1))
```

Or you can use formatting operators:

```
print('param1: %s' % (param1,))
print('param1: {}'.format(param1))
```

Comment: Thanks, good catch, but it still doesn't explain why print('param1: ' + param1) didn't throw an exception and print('param2: ' + param2) did.

Comment: @user3517351 - Because `param1` is `False` so the code under the first if-statement is never executed.